# Pasar por parametro una imagen

Tags: codeigniter

Hola quisiera saber como puedo hacer que una imagen (logo) cambie si voy a otra ventana.

Estoy realizando una aplicación web con *codeigniter* que trata sobre el registro de personas.

Quiero que cuando esté en un hotel, por ejemplo Barcelona, solo cambie el logo, el registro estará igual. Ahora, si en la url pongo valencia, me debe cambiar solo el logo, el formulario será igual.

He llegado hasta aquí:

Vista:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 768px)">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/bootstrap-switch.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/jquery-ui.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/hover.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/vendors/bower_components/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/vendors/bower_components/loaders.css/loaders.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/vendors/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/css/estilos.css">
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.formatCurrency-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.uitablefilter.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/vendors/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<style></style>
</head>
 <br>
 <br>
    <img src="<?= base_url('gallery/img').'/' .$img ?>" class="center-block">
 <hr>
<body>
```

Controlador:

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Empleado extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('empleado_model');
    }
    //CARGA DE LAS VISTAS Y DEL TITULO POR VARIABLE
    public function index()
     {
        if($img){
            $this->load->view('formu_views',$img);
        }
         $data['title']='Gallery Hoteles';
         $datos['img']=$img;
         $this->load->view('comun/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('formu_views',$data);
        $this->load->view('comun/footer',$data);
    }
    //INSERCION DE DATOS DEL REGISTRO EN BASE DE DATOS Y VALIDACION DE CAMPOS
    public function insertar()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nombre','nombre','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('papellido','primer apellido','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('sapellido','segundo apellido','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email','required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('ciudad','ciudad','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('empleado','nombre del empleado','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('terminos','terminos','callback_terminos');

        if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE){
            $datos['nombre']=set_value('nombre');
            $datos['papellido']=set_value('papellido');
            $datos['sapellido']=set_value('sapellido');
            $datos['email']=set_value('email');
            $datos['ciudad']=set_value('ciudad');
            $datos['empleado']=set_value('empleado');
            $datos['terminos']=set_value('terminos');
            $data['title']='Gallery Hoteles';
            $this->load->view('comun/header',$data);
            $this->load->view('formu_views',$datos);
            $this->load->view('comun/footer',$data);

        }else{
            $data = array(
                'nombre' =>$this->input->post('nombre'),
                'papellido'=>$this->input->post('papellido'),
                'sapellido'=>$this->input->post('sapellido'),
                'email'=> $this->input->post('email'),
                'ciudad'=> $this->input->post('ciudad'),
                'empleado'=>$this->input->post('empleado'),
                'fecha'=> date('Y-m-d  H:i:s'),
                'condiciones'=> 1,
                'firma'=>'fias'
            );
            $this->empleado_model->insertar($data);
            redirect('empleado');
         }
     }
    //CALLBACK DE LA VALIDACION DE TERMINOS
    public function terminos($data)
    {
        if (isset($_POST['terminos']))return true;
        $this->form_validation->set_message('terminos','Se deben aceptar los terminos y condiciones');
        return FALSE;
    }


}
```

Aquí no se como llamar a las 3 imágenes por la variable por el controlador.
Pongo la vista :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 768px)">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/bootstrap-switch.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/jquery-ui.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/hover.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/vendors/bower_components/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/vendors/bower_components/loaders.css/loaders.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/vendors/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/css/estilos.css">
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.formatCurrency-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.uitablefilter.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/vendors/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<style></style>
</head>
 <br>
 <br>
    <?php $img= 'gh_3.png' ?>
    <img src="<?=base_url('img/').$img?>" class="center-block">
 <hr>
<body>
<!-- Fin del header -->
```

Comment: Con solo la **vista** poco podemos ver ahí. Al parecer desde el **controlador** envías la variable **$img** que es la que me imagino que contiene el nombre de la imagen. Lo único que tendrías que hacer es modificar la función del **controlador** que llama a la **vista** para que el valor de **$img** sea diferente dependiendo del hotel al que tengas que servir el formulario. Eso podrías determinarlo con el **base_url()** para generar una condición.

Comment: De acuerdo, no puse el código del controlador porque solo avance hasta poner la variable en la vista, con lo que me has dicho he hecho esto. Si no es molestia que me ayudaras porf. Te adjunto el controlador

Comment: ¿Con qué campo quieres identificar el hotel al que se está registrando? ¿Con $datos['ciudad']=set_value('ciudad');? ¿Tienes solamente un hotel por ciudad? Es mejor que borres la respuesta que has dado a tu pregunta, el procedimiento correcto es editar tu pregunta para añadir más contenido.

Comment: Solo son 3 por ciudades, Barcelona, Málaga y Valencia, ahora lo que estoy haciendo es esto. Cargo en la vista     <?php $img= 'gh_3.png' ?>
    <img src="<?=base_url('img/').$img?>" class="center-block">

Comment: Ahora lo que quiero es pasar por medio de la imagen guardada en la variable en el controlador

Comment: Vuelve a poner el controlador, pero editando tu pregunta en vez de creando una respuesta nueva, que si no me dejas a ciegas de nuevo.